# Issue with jmeter while executing .bat file

Tags: jmeter

The following error shown in that command prompt

java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences 
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0
x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.

Answer (score 0):

seems a problem of Windows registry key. Try create the key yourself. Added the

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs
```

PS: Can depends of your operating system version.